# Gauge D3.js display value at the top of the needle

Tags: javascript, d3.js, gauge

I'm kinda new to D3.js, and I managed to create a gauge with what I found on the Internet. But I couldn't find any gauge showing the current value at the top of the needle.
Something like this : [what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UfubO.png)

Obviously I'd like the value to follow the needle. I tried to add "text" attribute to the needle itself, but it didn't work.

Here's a codepen link : http://codepen.io/kazu_codepen/pen/wGmGjv?editors=1010

Here's my js code :

```
// data which need to be fetched

var name = "azerty";

var value = 17;


var gaugeMaxValue = 100; 

// data to calculate 
var percentValue = value / gaugeMaxValue; 

////////////////////////

var needleClient;



(function(){

var barWidth, chart, chartInset, degToRad, repaintGauge,
    height, margin, numSections, padRad, percToDeg, percToRad, 
    percent, radius, sectionIndx, svg, totalPercent, width;



  percent = percentValue;

  numSections = 1;
  sectionPerc = 1 / numSections / 2;
  padRad = 0.025;
  chartInset = 10;

  // Orientation of gauge:
  totalPercent = .75;

  el = d3.select('.chart-gauge');

  margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 20
  };

  width = el[0][0].offsetWidth - margin.left - margin.right;
  height = width;
  radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;
  barWidth = 40 * width / 300;



  //Utility methods 

  percToDeg = function(perc) {
    return perc * 360;
  };

  percToRad = function(perc) {
    return degToRad(percToDeg(perc));
  };

  degToRad = function(deg) {
    return deg * Math.PI / 180;
  };

  // Create SVG element
  svg = el.append('svg').attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right).attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom);

  // Add layer for the panel
  chart = svg.append('g').attr('transform', "translate(" + ((width + margin.left) / 2) + ", " + ((height + margin.top) / 2) + ")");


  chart.append('path').attr('class', "arc chart-first");
  chart.append('path').attr('class', "arc chart-second");
  chart.append('path').attr('class', "arc chart-third");


  arc3 = d3.svg.arc().outerRadius(radius - chartInset).innerRadius(radius - chartInset - barWidth)
  arc2 = d3.svg.arc().outerRadius(radius - chartInset).innerRadius(radius - chartInset - barWidth)
  arc1 = d3.svg.arc().outerRadius(radius - chartInset).innerRadius(radius - chartInset - barWidth)

  repaintGauge = function () 
  {
    perc = 0.5;
    var next_start = totalPercent;
    arcStartRad = percToRad(next_start);
    arcEndRad = arcStartRad + percToRad(perc / 3);
    next_start += perc / 3;


    arc1.startAngle(arcStartRad).endAngle(arcEndRad);

    arcStartRad = percToRad(next_start);
    arcEndRad = arcStartRad + percToRad(perc / 3);
    next_start += perc / 3;

    arc2.startAngle(arcStartRad + padRad).endAngle(arcEndRad);

    arcStartRad = percToRad(next_start);
    arcEndRad = arcStartRad + percToRad(perc / 3);

    arc3.startAngle(arcStartRad + padRad).endAngle(arcEndRad);

    chart.select(".chart-first").attr('d', arc1);
    chart.select(".chart-second").attr('d', arc2);
    chart.select(".chart-third").attr('d', arc3);


  }
/////////

    var dataset = [{metric:name, value: value}]

    var texts = svg.selectAll("text")
                .data(dataset)
                .enter();

    texts.append("text")
         .text(function(){
              return dataset[0].metric;
         })
         .attr('id', "Name")
         .attr('transform', "translate(" + ((width + margin.left) / 6) + ", " + ((height + margin.top) / 1.5) + ")")
         .attr("font-size",25)
         .style("fill", "#000000");


    texts.append("text")
         .text(function(){
            return dataset[0].value;
         })
         .attr('id', "Value")
         .attr('transform', "translate(" + ((width + margin.left) / 1.4) + ", " + ((height + margin.top) / 1.5) + ")")
         .attr("font-size",25)
         .style("fill", "#000000");




    texts.append("text")
        .text(function(){
            return 0;
        })
        .attr('id', 'scale0')
        .attr('transform', "translate(" + ((width + margin.left) / 100 ) + ", " + ((height + margin.top) / 2) + ")")
        .attr("font-size", 15)
        .style("fill", "#000000");

    texts.append("text")
        .text(function(){
            return gaugeMaxValue/2;
        })
        .attr('id', 'scale10')
        .attr('transform', "translate(" + ((width + margin.left) / 2.15 ) + ", " + ((height + margin.top) / 30) + ")")
        .attr("font-size", 15)
        .style("fill", "#000000");


    texts.append("text")
        .text(function(){
            return gaugeMaxValue;
        })
        .attr('id', 'scale20')
        .attr('transform', "translate(" + ((width + margin.left) / 1.03 ) + ", " + ((height + margin.top) / 2) + ")")
        .attr("font-size", 15)
        .style("fill", "#000000");

  var Needle = (function() {

    //Helper function that returns the `d` value for moving the needle
    var recalcPointerPos = function(perc) {
      var centerX, centerY, leftX, leftY, rightX, rightY, thetaRad, topX, topY;
      thetaRad = percToRad(perc / 2);
      centerX = 0;
      centerY = 0;
      topX = centerX - this.len * Math.cos(thetaRad);
      topY = centerY - this.len * Math.sin(thetaRad);
      leftX = centerX - this.radius * Math.cos(thetaRad - Math.PI / 2);
      leftY = centerY - this.radius * Math.sin(thetaRad - Math.PI / 2);
      rightX = centerX - this.radius * Math.cos(thetaRad + Math.PI / 2);
      rightY = centerY - this.radius * Math.sin(thetaRad + Math.PI / 2);
      return "M " + leftX + " " + leftY + " L " + topX + " " + topY + " L " + rightX + " " + rightY;
    };

    function Needle(el) {
      this.el = el;
      this.len = width / 2.5;
      this.radius = this.len / 8;
    }

    Needle.prototype.render = function() {
      this.el.append('circle').attr('class', 'needle-center').attr('cx', 0).attr('cy', 0).attr('r', this.radius);

        ///////
        /**
        *
        * I tried to add text here
        *
        */
        ///////

      return this.el.append('path').attr('class', 'needle').attr('id', 'client-needle').attr('d', recalcPointerPos.call(this, 0));


    };

    Needle.prototype.moveTo = function(perc) {
      var self,
          oldValue = this.perc || 0;

      this.perc = perc;
      self = this;

      // Reset pointer position
      this.el.transition().delay(100).ease('quad').duration(200).select('.needle').tween('reset-progress', function() {
        return function(percentOfPercent) {
          var progress = (1 - percentOfPercent) * oldValue;

          repaintGauge(progress);
          return d3.select(this).attr('d', recalcPointerPos.call(self, progress));
        };
      });

      this.el.transition().delay(300).ease('bounce').duration(1500).select('.needle').tween('progress', function() {
        return function(percentOfPercent) {
          var progress = percentOfPercent * perc;

          repaintGauge(progress);
          return d3.select(this).attr('d', recalcPointerPos.call(self, progress));
        };
      });

    };


    return Needle;

  })();



  needle = new Needle(chart);
  needle.render();
  needle.moveTo(percent);   

})();
```

And here's my html code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <style type="text/css" src="gauge.css">
            .chart-gauge
            {
              width: 400px;
              margin: 100px auto  
             } 
            .chart-first
            {
                fill: #9FBD35;
            }
            .chart-second
            {
                fill: #F2BA3A;
            }
            .chart-third
            {
                fill: #FB3033;
            }

            .needle, .needle-center
            {
                fill: #000000;
            }
            .text {
                color: "#112864";
                font-size: 16px;
            }


            svg {
              font: 10px sans-serif;
            }


        </style>

    </head>
    <body>


        <div class="chart-gauge"></div>



        <script type="text/javascript" src="./gaugeClient.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./labels.js"></script>
        <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    </body>

</html>
```

If anyone could help, I've spent few days trying unsuccessfully.
Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's an [updated codepen](http://codepen.io/meetamit/pen/xOgeoj)

#### Changes made:

1) As part of initialization, create element `valueText`

```
valueText = chart.append("text")
                .attr('id', "Value")
                .attr("font-size",16)
                .attr("text-anchor","middle")
                .attr("dy",".5em")
                .style("fill", '#000000');
```

2) Also at initialization, create `formatValue`, to format percent

```
formatValue = d3.format('1%');
```

3) At each frame of the transition, compute the position of the text. It adds an offset of `45` units to `self.len` (the needle's length) to move the text outwards.

```
var thetaRad = percToRad(progress / 2);
var textX = - (self.len + 45) * Math.cos(thetaRad);
var textY = - (self.len + 45) * Math.sin(thetaRad);
```

4) Translate `valueText` based on the computed position and update its text from current `progress`

```
valueText.text(formatValue(progress))
  .attr('transform', "translate("+textX+","+textY+")")
```

Comment: Thanks first for your answer, it works perfectly ! If I want a number like 1.45 and not a %, I should use d3.format(.3) right ?

Comment: Not quite. `d3.format(.2f)` formats as a float with precision 2 decimal places, which would make `1.45`. There's a chance you'll need to multiply by 100 the value you pass to this formatter.

Comment: @meetamit No problem, great answer! Thanks for the contribution!

Comment: I did just notice that once you start using `valueText = chart.append("text")`,  it makes all the texts such as the name which was below the gauge. Any idea why and how to display that name ?

Comment: @kazu, Sorry, I don't understand the problem. Can you clarify what you mean?

Comment: Well, depending on where you put `valueText = chart.append("text")` in the code, some part of the texts might not appear. For example, if you let it where you put it in the code, "azerty" which was displayed below the gauge won't appear, but if you move it elsewhere, after `var texts = svg.selectAll("text")` it works properly.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found out something waiting for a better solution.

I'm using this :

```
var trX = 180 - 210 * Math.cos(percToRad(percent / 2)); 
var trY = 195 - 210 * Math.sin(percToRad(percent / 2));
// (180, 195) are the coordinates of the center of the gauge.

displayValue = function() {
                texts.append("text")
                    .text(function(){
                        return dataset[0].value;
                    })
                    .attr('id', "Value")
                    .attr('transform', "translate(" + trX + ", " + trY+ ")")
                    .attr("font-size",18)
                    .style("fill", '#FB0006');
            }
```

[...] then calling this :

```
setTimeout(displayValue, 1350);
```

So that it doesn't appear right away, but when the needle has stopped at its position.

It works, in the way that the value appears on the top of the needle, but I still have two problems.
I'd really like it to follow the needle all the way long during the needle animation when it goes to its value, and I'd like something more general than using the coordinates I found out by calculating, is there a function which can give me the center of the gauge for example ?

I edited the pen given above to that version of the gauge. (http://codepen.io/kazu_codepen/pen/wGmGjv?editors=1010)

Anyway, this solution doesn't really fit my expectations, but I'll use it till I can find something better.

Comment: Hi Kazu, I was wondering if you could share the calculation you used to find the coordinates?

Comment: Well, sadly I don't really have a method here. I first found out the coordinates of the center of the gauge, then I tried few values to find the good radius and it worked somehow. Sorry that I can't help.
 I'd be really interested if someone knows a way to calculate this properly though !