# How to make a C3 donut chart to a semi circle or a half donut chart in typescript?

Tags: typescript, d3.js, charts, c3.js, donut-chart

Is it possible to create a half donut chart or a semi circle donut chart by modifying the C3 library code with a start angle and an end angle?

[Trying to make something like the image in d3/c3 with typescript](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8kgB.png)

Comment: This [bl.ock](http://bl.ocks.org/mikeyao/b5ae6670a1c1a60724c63d034bb3b8ca) shows how to do it in d3.js. I only say this because this post is also tagged `d3.js`. Then from there you could modify it to be Typescipt.

Comment: Thanks for the block but I am also looking for the legends toggling functionality as in the image above. Achieving all this in angular with d3 is the problem I am facing. There aren't simply enough examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A donut is just a pie chart with a blank center. A gauge is closer to what you are displaying. 
c3.js has a [gauge chart](http://c3js.org/samples/chart_gauge.html).

The dial color changes as the values go past thresholds. 
You want to show more than one parameter, eg. 50% in progress, of which 30% passed, 20% failed. etc. This is like a [stacked](http://c3js.org/samples/chart_bar_stacked.html) chart, but displayed in an arc. For this you you want to specify a pattern.

There are some examples buried in the [source code](https://github.com/c3js/c3/blob/master/htdocs/samples/chart_multi_arc_gauge.html). Try this:

```
this.chart = c3.generate({
      bindto: bindToThis,
      data: {
        columns: [
          ['padded1', 100],
          ['padded2', 90],
          ['padded3', 50],
          ['padded4', 20]
        ],
        type: 'gauge',
      },
      color: {
        pattern: ['#FF0000', '#F97600', '#F6C600', '#60B044'],
        threshold: {
          values: [30, 80, 95]
        }
      }
```

Which renders as 
[image]

For typescript, there are some angular components like https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-gauge.  I can't find one that shows multiple variables without modification.

See also these examples in D3 that could be modified to dynamically change the background arcs angles to track the measured variables. The needle is optional.

[How to customise Gauge needle pointer using D3.js or C3.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50644710/how-to-customise-gauge-needle-pointer-using-d3-js-or-c3-js/50645427)

Or [Gauge D3.js display value at the top of the needle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36592648/gauge-d3-js-display-value-at-the-top-of-the-needle)
[enter link description here](https://github.com/c3js/c3/blob/master/htdocs/samples/chart_multi_arc_gauge.html)

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed explanation but when I am getting a different chart where the arc isnt stacked but has parallel multiple arcs.

Comment: I am getting this [link](https://imgur.com/a/OmZMnX1) . How can I achieve the chart similar to the image you provided above?

Comment: It turns out that image was from an older version of c3. The latest library renders as per the threshold which is now mandatory. Have posted a question to the c3 google group https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/c3js/gauge%7Csort:date/c3js/BY2Sc__4mUA/S5XVZ_qSBQAJ

Comment: Did anyone ever figure this out? I can't believe they removed the ability to allow this to work. Seems like working backwards...

Comment: @wuno I gave up and used Chart.js for this particular chart. Rest everything is C3!

Comment: @NishantKoli thanks for getting back to me. I also ended up on the same path till I found this, http://bernii.github.io/gauge.js/